# is it possible to turn a JList selectedIndex into an object?

Tags: java, swing, awt

This is a small test sample of a bigger project so i quickly threw a simple frame window, I want to be able to get the selection from the list and turn it into an object so I can grab the getter methods (getName, getTime, etc) to slap onto a JLabel.
FYI, the toArray() is a method I wrote that just returns (getName() + "" +getTime())

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("skinDoctor.dat");
    ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(file);

    Doctor doctor0 = (Doctor) o.readObject();
    Doctor doctor1 = (Doctor) o.readObject();

    String[] listX = {doctor0.toArray(), doctor1.toArray()};
    JList<String> list = new JList<>(listX);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(list);
}
```

Would it go something like this? or is it just not possible

```
if(list.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
        //Something here to turn it into an object
    }
```

Comment: Don't attempt to turn the String into an Object. Instead, you would add the `Doctor` object directly to the `JList` so you can then get the `Doctor` object when needed. So, when you create the JList you use `JList<Doctor>`. Read the JList API. You will find other "getter" methods that allow you to get the selected `Doctor` object. You will then need to create a custom renderer to display the appropriate information from the `Doctor` object.

Comment: The Swing tutorial has an example of creating a [custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). The example is for a combo box, but the concept is the same.